# Ошибка при использовании COLUMNPROPERTY, при попытке изменить значение в столбце

Tags: sql, sql-server

Такая задача стоит.
Если в таблице есть столбец, то мы меняем его значение на цифры или буквы. Если столбца нет, то ничего не делаем.

Более глобальная задача - перебрать все таблицы в БД, проверить есть ли в каждой таблице определенный столбец и изменить данные во всех строках, если в таблице такого столбца нет, то ничего не делать

О существовании процедуры [sp_MSforeachtable] знаю, но пока не могу сложить 2+2, чтобы заработало все. Решил попробовать с небольших задач, а далее подтянуть уже эту процедуру. Если кто-нибудь сможет дать развернутый ответ, буду очень рад, уже дня 4 сижу обдумываю и пробую как бы это все осуществить..

Есть Таблица 1, у нее есть столбцы "Пол", "USERID". Всего 3 записи в таблице
Если условие верно, то я хочу изменить в этой таблице значения в столбце USERID и вывести все столбцы для проверки.

В чем проблема. Если я указываю значение, на которое нужно заменить в виде цифр, то все работает.

```
if COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id('Таблица 1'), 'Пол', 'ColumnId') is not null 
 exec ('update "Таблица 1" set [USERID] = 666');
 exec ('SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Таблица 1]');
```

Если же я указываю значение в виде строки, то получаю ошибку

```
if COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id('Таблица 1'), 'Пол', 'ColumnId') is not null 
 exec ('update "Таблица 1" set [USERID] = "test"');
 exec ('SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Таблица 1]');
```

Ошибка:

Сообщение 207, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 1
Недопустимое имя столбца "asd".

(затронуто строк: 3)

Подскажите почему вываливается ошибка и как ее можно обойти.
Предполагаю, что ошибка появляется потому что возвращаемое значение функции int
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/columnproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Если мое предположение верно, то как можно обойти или доработать данный вопрос.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Метка mysql зачем?

Comment: Приведенный код не может вызвать ошибку _Недопустимое имя столбца "asd"._, потому что в нем просто неоткуда взяться сочетанию букв "asd".

Comment: @Yaant 
Доброе утро. Действительно я неверно скопировал 2 строчки.
Код ошибки:

Ошибка:

Сообщение 207, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 1 Недопустимое имя столбца "test".

(затронуто строк: 3)

Comment: Потому что строки пишутся в одинарных кавычках. В двойных пишутся имена столбцов. `exec ('update "Таблица 1" set [USERID] = ''test''');`

Comment: @Yaant Спасибо!